# Sort a list using another list as a path

Tags: python

It is an begginer question, but...

I have a list of characters

```
list = [b, d, c, f, e, a]
```

and another list with the path.

```
path = [5, 0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

How I can get the following output?

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Comment: So why you need the list called `path` ? Your output needs only `list`.

Comment: I think you got the `output` wrong

Comment: Don't call your `list`, `list`, it shadows the builtin name [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). And will surely give you problems down the line

Comment: I flagged this question as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @GarrettR That's how I interpreted the question at first, but it does not match OP's expected output. In fact, I think all those massively downvoted answers got it exactly right.

Comment: what do you mean with path? because `list.sort()` give you the list `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`

Comment: If you need a generic sort, where the **path** list isn't simply the indices of the **list** list (note the problem with your variable names), you can find answers easily by searching this very group for a sort using another list as the key.  You should have made this search before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to get the list composed of `list[i]` for each index in the same order as in `path` ? Just keep it stupid simple and do what you need to do:

```
[list[i] for i in path]
```

Comment: As simple as it is, I think this is actually what OP is looking for, although the questions is somewhat misleading.

Comment: This is correct answer , but we shouldn't give right answer to OP that didn't have tried anything so far.

Comment: @Arman Just because there is no evidence that Fábio Alves tried anything does not mean that we need to take that as proof that he has not tried anything. The question and answer may still provide help to others.